# How to get files stored in inbuilt external storage

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

I had created a mdatabase.db file on the sdcard in a directory named MyDataBase, this is fine, when i open the sdcard via phone the dir and files are showing, but when i connected the device to system and open via system the created files are not showing.
Help me please

This problem is arriving only in inbuilt sdcard devices for me

**DataBasepath**
mnt/sdcard/MyDataBase/mdatabase.db

Comment: did check the fileexplorer

Comment: where your database stored? can you provide full path?

Comment: @ChintanRathod given above

Answer (score 0):

use this code to Checking media availability

```
boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // We can only read the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
} else {
    // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other states, but all we need
    //  to know is we can neither read nor write
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}
```

do your code depend on that

[for more detail](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)